# Bind9 fails to start

Tags: 11.04, server

After 3 weeks of trying to diagnose a failure of bind9, to start I have to admit I need assistance.

Initially it was running correctly and when I made a modification to a bind file and re-run it an error msg came back

```
rndc: 127.0.0.1#953 bind9 start fail
```

It also fails to start on any other `bind9` upgrade or required pkg.

`grep` on `mysql` returns nothing now even if it is running, and `dig` on 127 only works when I have my phone connected as a modem.

I don't have any more diagnostics that I know of, so some help would be appreciated as development has stopped.

Comment: Try to remove completely, then reinstall `bind9`: `sudo apt-get purge bind9 && sudo apt-get --reinstall install bind9`. You will loose local configurations, if you have them.

Comment: Do you have anything in the bind9 logs? IIRC they are located in /var/log/bind9/

Answer (score 5):

*As mentioned in the comments by enzotib*

---

Try to remove completely, then reinstall bind9: `sudo apt-get purge bind9 && sudo apt-get --reinstall install bind9`. You will loose local configurations, if you have them.

Comment: kindly mark the question as answered, if you get the answer